# What should be the error code for invalid path parameter/query parameter

Tags: java, api, web-services, restful-url

I am a little confused about what should a service return for invalid path parameter and invalid query parameter.
Especially for path parameters, nobody able confirm whether it is 400 or 404.

Let's say following is the service endpoint : [https://samples-service.com/rest/v1/qvc/{countryCode}/users?numberOfusers=10](https://samples-service.com/rest/v1/qvc/%7BcountryCode%7D/users?numberOfusers=10)

**countryCode is the path parameter.**

- Acceptable country codes are US and UK.
- If a user enters an incorrect country code, what should be the response? 400 Bad Request or 404 Not Found?

I have heard people provide justification for both of these responses.

*J**ustification for 404:**
If the user tries to hit an invalid path then the service should return 404 Not Found. So since it is a path parameter, it should 404*

***Justification for 400**
Since is the incorrect parameter. It should be 404. Doesn't matter whether it is a path parameter or query parameter or payload*

For me, both of these make kind of sense. Not sure which is the correct one.

**numberOfusers is the query parameter**
If a user enters an invalid number (eg: negative number, -9). What should the service return 400 or 404.
I think in this case 400 is acceptable. But just want to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you identity a resource using a path parameter or a query parameter, you're identifying a resource, so if it isn't found, you return **`404 Not Found`**.

*Examples*

```
https://samples-service.com/rest/v1/qvc/{countryCode}/users
https://samples-service.com/rest/v1/qvc/users?countryCode={countryCode}
```

If the request has query parameters that have defined restrictions, e.g. `pageSize` must be between 1 and 100 inclusive, then a value outside that range is *invalid*, and you should return **`400 Bad Request`**.

*Examples*

```
https://samples-service.com/rest/v1/qvc/US/users?pageSize=0
https://samples-service.com/rest/v1/qvc/users?countryCode=US&pageSize=0
```